# Counting comparisons in Heapsort using C#

Tags: c#, sorting, heapsort

I have a heapsort algorithm.

```
private int heapSize;

    private void BuildHeap(int[] arr)
    {
        heapSize = arr.Length - 1;
        for (int i = heapSize / 2; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            Heapify(arr, i);
        }
    }

    private void Swap(int[] arr, int x, int y)//function to swap elements
    {
        int temp = arr[x];
        arr[x] = arr[y];
        arr[y] = temp;

    }
    private void Heapify(int[] arr, int index)
    {
        int left = 2 * index + 1;
        int right = 2 * index + 2;
        int largest = index;
        if (left <= heapSize && arr[left] > arr[index])
        {
            largest = left;
        }

        if (right <= heapSize && arr[right] > arr[largest])
        {
            largest = right;
        }

        if (largest != index)
        {
            Swap(arr, index, largest);
            Heapify(arr, largest);
        }
    }
    public int PerformHeapSortTest(int[] arr)
    {
        int counter = 0;
        BuildHeap(arr);
        for (int i = arr.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            Swap(arr, 0, i);
            heapSize--;
            Heapify(arr, 0);
        }
   DisplayArray(arr);
    }
  Private void DisplayArray(int[] arr)
    {
      for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
         {Console.Write("{0}\n", arr[i])}
    }
```

I want to count the comparisons and don't understand how to implement this using this heap sort algorithm which is in a separate class which I call from the main. I have looked around online and can't find anything. Could some one show me how to implement comparisons to this algorithm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement your comparisons using Compare method instead of using operators. Please see full answer here (answer post): [how to count heapsort key comparisons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19939458/how-to-count-heapsort-key-comparisons)